# Disable previous dates in datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I tried to use datepicker for a form on my website from a following link. I want to disable previous dates and only allow user to select date from current date and onward.
    http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?markup=input&format=&weekStart=&startDate=&endDate=&startView=0&minViewMode=0&todayBtn=false&clearBtn=false&language=en&orientation=auto&multidate=&multidateSeparator=&keyboardNavigation=on&forceParse=on#sandbox

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
            $('#sandbox-container input').datepicker({
                format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
                clearBtn: true,
                minDate: 0, 
                maxDate: "+1M +10D",
                daysOfWeekDisabled: "0,6"

            });
});
```

I add following code `minDate: 0,maxDate: "+1M +10D"` to achieve this, but its not working. Also I need to add time in this datepicker if it is possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please use `$('#sandbox-container')` instead of `$('#sandbox-container input')`.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  $('#sandbox-container').datepicker({
    format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
    clearBtn: true,
    minDate: 0,
    maxDate: "+1M +10D",
    daysOfWeekDisabled: "0,6"

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


Date :
<input id="sandbox-container" type="text">
```

Please visit below links:

http://www.dotnetlearners.com/blogs/view/98/JQuery-Date-Picker-example-to-disable-previous-dates.aspx

Comment: I tried by doing exactly the same, but its not working :( .. It is working with daysOfWeekDisabled: "0,6" but i don't know why its not working with minDate:0;

Comment: @Aeykash Did you check jsfiddle link, I provided you with exact code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this is disable past dates

```
var dateToday = new Date();
$(document).ready(function () { 
            $('#sandbox-container input').datepicker({
                format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
                clearBtn: true,
                 minDate: dateToday,                
                daysOfWeekDisabled: "0,6"

            });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest solution is to set today's date as minDate in datepicker as below. This will block all the dates prior to today's date.

```
$('#sandbox-container input')
  .datepicker({
     format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
     minDate: new Date(),                
   });
```

Above is sample code just to illustrate how can you set `minDate`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('#sandbox-container input')
  .datepicker({
     format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
     minDate: new Date(),                
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find the details

Html code for date

```
<input type="text" id="dateRange" />
```

JS code

```
 $("#dateRange").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        hideIfNoPrevNext: true,
        dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
        minDate: 0
    });
```

The will disable all the dates less current date

Answer (score 0):

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  $('#sandbox-container').datepicker({
    format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
    clearBtn: true,
    minDate: 0,
    maxDate: "+1M +10D",
    daysOfWeekDisabled: "0,6"

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


Date :
<input id="sandbox-container" type="text">
```

I want disable only from 2nd date before current date. Please provide me code for it.